# Why is expo apk file very large even with just one screen code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

My expo apk file has a size of 45.8 MB.

Look at the apk size in the screenshot below.

- [App Info on Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ef5z.jpg)
- [Expo apk size Vs android studio apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnae4.jpg)

How can I get a smaller APK-Size?

Comment: If you are building React native app using expo size will be large since it contain many in build libraries, If you want to reduce size , please use React Native CLI , Reference : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many way's to reduce the size of your distributed app. 
I'm afraid you have to read & learn something about this, because this isn't a short & easy answer - at least, because there are many hooks where you can adjust your deployment-process to optimize your app(size).

But here some first suggestions:

1. If possible use `React Native CLI` to initialize your Project (instead of EXPO)
2. Don't use an existing React-Native Module for each stuff you do. Sometimes it gives you a lower footprint to code easy stuff by your own instead to import an npm-module from third-party
3. Keep your files (audio, video, images) bundled with your app as low as possible, think about to use SVG where possible.
4. Better use "app-bundle" for Android-Apps as general "apk-releases" (keyword: `gradlew 
   bundleRelease` vs `gradlew assembleRelease`)
5. Don't miss to read the [Performance Section](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance) in React-Native Docs
6. `build.gradle` gives you additional Options to optimize your App for bundling-Process. Be sure that you use Proguard with shrinkRessources to minimize your apk / bundle (keywords: Proguard, seperateBuildPerCPUArchitecture)

**PS:** Best result you can gain, with lowest effort to spend (only for Android-Apps): Switch from APK to Bundle (AAP) [see Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-apk)

Comment: Thanks for your response...
can i switch expo cli project to react native cli project?

Comment: I think you can eject your expo-Project, or generate a new `cli-project` and migrate your data. Here I've found a nice article which should give you an Idea for that: https://medium.com/reactbrasil/being-free-from-expo-in-react-native-apps-310034a3729